# Does Facebook's OpenGraph support language-only locales?

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/ says "Facebook locales follow ISO language and country codes respectively, concatenated by an underscore.".

So would it accept "en" or is it mandatory to include "en-us" "en-gb" etc?

(I have some auto-detected languages where only the language, not the region, is known.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must use the ll_CC format. If you can't figure out which region the language belongs to, you can make an educated guess. See what regions are avaiable for that language by taking a look at the [Translation XML file](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml). You can even parse this at run-time if that works for your application.

Comment: I guess I'll skip on the English (Pirate) option :).

Comment: Don't forget the Upside Down English.

Comment: It's weird that only full `ll_CC` locales are supported, specially since proprietary umbrella locales such as `es_LA` do exist. It would be both a simple and useful extension to allow language-only locales `ll` which summon all territories of that language. Here's my chat with The Thumb on this topic:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/766138066785466/